# Photoshop PDF not appearing in Save As - too large document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, print-production, file-format, size

I've got a banner that is 43,000px x 8,500px @96dpi done in Photoshop but the PDF option does not come up in the Save As. Only if I reduce it to 30,000px across will the Save As PDF option come up. Is there an inherent limitation for PDF sizes in Photoshop or PDF's in general? Any help to get around this would be great. The printer guy wants it in a PDF. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about that limitation in Photoshop. I never save PDF from PS, but instead place the image in a InDesign or Illustrator document with the wanted physical dimensions and export a PDF from there. Perhaps you can try that. (And if the banner is mostly vector graphics and text it would be easier to do the whole thing in InDesign/Illustrator to begin with)

Comment: Photoshop dies not save anything other than psb when size is over 30,000

Comment: Thanks very much for the tips. I'll do the In-Design trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
The printer guy wants it in a PDF..
```

Yes, and the printer guy also probably knows this should not be a Photoshop PDF — which is limited, Photoshop was not made for this purpose.

The printer guy can probably confirm you need to drag that image into InDesign and export a for-real-to-print InDesign PDF.

Yes, you can drag (aka. *link*) a Photoshop file (aka. *PSD*) into InDesign.

Also, when printing at this size, you never, ever, think in pixels. The printer guy should give you sizing in *Centimeters* or *Inches*, depending on your location.

Pixels are for used for screens — laptops, tablets, smartphones, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that.